# Why is npm start error creating react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, npm

**I'm learning reactjs
I started with installing nodejs
and then ran these commands inside my project folder "React"**

```
npx create-react-app hello-world
cd hello-world
npm start
```

**but then instead of going to the browser i receive error:**

> npm ERR! missing script: start
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-21T13_34_26_640Z-debug.log

**PACKAGE.JSON CODE:**

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  }
}
```

Help me solve this error i dont want it to demotivate me from learning React

Answer (score 1):

npm scripts are missing inside your `package.json` file

> npm ERR! missing script: start

Edit your `package.json` as follows:

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response. I tried editing the package.json file like you guided but still got errors.  C:\Users\abc\Desktop\React\hello-world>npm start

> hello-world@0.1.0 start C:\Users\abc\Desktop\React\hello-world
> react-scripts start

Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: C:\Users\abc\Desktop\React\hello-world\public
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello-world@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! Failed at the hello-world@0.1.0 start script.

Comment: Something went wrong when you ran "npx create-react-app hello-world". These files should all be present if it completed properly.

Comment: what's your version of node ? Run `node -v` to find out

Comment: my node version is 12.12.0

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing almost same type of problem. But then tried

`yarn create react-app my-app`

in power shell with admin privilege which seemed to do the trick.

> Also you’ll need to have Node >= 8.10, yarn >= 0.25+ on your machine
> as the official doc suggests.